# Open in new window

Tags: php, html

Trying to open a new window using a tag using target attribute but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $count;?>
    </td>
    <td><a class="oiu" href=<?php echo "eventdetail.php?idno=".$row[ 'E_id'];?>><u><?php echo $row['E_name'];?></u></a>
    </td>
    <td><a class="oiu" href=<?php echo "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=".$cadd. "&daddr=".$vadd;?> target="_blank" ><u><?php echo $row['Venue'];?><u></a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row[ 'EDate']. '  '.$time;?>
    </td>
    <!-- <td><div id="remain"><?php echo "$days, $hours:$minutes:$seconds";?></div></td> -->
    <td> <a class="icon1" href=<?php echo "update.php?idno=".$eid;?>><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pencil"></span></a><a class="icon2" href="#myModal2" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash trash"></span></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php $count++;
```

Comment: Not working how? You are clicking the venue link, right? Also you aren't closing the underlining there. You should quote your attribute values.

Comment: can you write the chnages i need to make in this code

Comment: I dont know the changes you need to make, you didn't answer any of my questions..

Comment: You aren't closing `</u>` Underline tag, place your href tag value inside single quotes...

Answer (score 0):

Make your `target="_blank"` first then give your `href="link"` as given below  and close the underline tag `</u>`.

Try the following code:

```
<tr>
<td><?php echo $count;?></td>
<td ><a class="oiu" href=<?php echo "eventdetail.php?idno=".$row['E_id'];?>><u><?php echo $row['E_name'];?></u></a></td>
<td><a class="oiu" target="_blank" href=<?php echo "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=".$cadd."&daddr=".$vadd;?>  ><u><?php echo $row['Venue'];?></u></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['EDate'].'  '.$time;?></td>
        <!-- <td><div id="remain"><?php echo "$days, $hours:$minutes:$seconds";?></div></td> -->
        <td> <a class="icon1" href=<?php echo "update.php?idno=".$eid;?>><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pencil"></span></a><a class="icon2" href="#myModal2" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash trash"></span></a></td>
    </tr>
```